# Netbeans+Glassfish отваливается

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Суть в следующем
имеется netbeans 8.0
glassfish 4.0
простейшее веб приложение в одну пару jsp страниц
воообщем Glassfish изначально работает корректно,а через некоторое время при редеплое  приложения сначала вылазит ошибка какой-то java DB:

> Fri Jan 25 23:24:56 GMT+03:00 2019 : Сетевой сервер Apache Derby
>   Network Server - 10.9.1.0 - (1344872) запущен и готов принимать
>   соединения на порту 1527 на {3}  Fri Jan 25 23:26:17 GMT+03:00 2019 :
>   Execution failed because of a Distributed Protocol Error: 
>   DRDA_Proto_SYNTAXRM; CODPNT arg  = 0; Error Code Value = 3. Plaintext
>   connection attempt from an SSL enabled client?
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAProtocolException: Execution failed
>   because of a Distributed Protocol Error:  DRDA_Proto_SYNTAXRM; CODPNT
>   arg  = 0; Error Code Value = 3. Plaintext connection attempt from an
>   SSL enabled client?   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.throwSyntaxrm(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DDMReader.readDssHeader(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.exchangeServerAttributes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.sessionInitialState(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown
>   Source) Fri Jan 25 23:26:17 GMT+03:00 2019 : Execution failed because
>   of a Distributed Protocol Error:  DRDA_Proto_SYNTAXRM; CODPNT arg  =
>   0; Error Code Value = 3. Plaintext connection attempt from an SSL
>   enabled client? org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAProtocolException:
>   Execution failed because of a Distributed Protocol Error: 
>   DRDA_Proto_SYNTAXRM; CODPNT arg  = 0; Error Code Value = 3. Plaintext
>   connection attempt from an SSL enabled client?    at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.throwSyntaxrm(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DDMReader.readDssHeader(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.exchangeServerAttributes(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.sessionInitialState(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

далее любые действия с Glassfish из нетбинса кроме удаления становятся инактивными-я не могу не перезапустить,ни стартануть заново сервер.можно лишь перезапустить NetBeans -сделать запуск Glassfish и получить эту же ошибку.

изначально эта непонятная java db ( что это вообще такое) и просила отключить проверку безопасности вроде. В общем сервер работает где-то часа два три потом падает и лечится это только полной переустановкой NetBeans + Glassfish

Логи Glassfish:

> Loading application [__admingui] at [/]]]
>   [2019-01-25T22:49:50.981+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [NCLS-CORE-00022] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=95
>   _ThreadName=Thread-11] [timeMillis: 1548445790981] [levelValue: 800] [[   Loading application __admingui done in 4 740 ms]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:10:33.932+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447033932] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:10:33.987+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447033987] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:10:33.993+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447033993] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:10:34.245+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447034245] [levelValue: 800] [[   Loading application [OnlineStore] at
>   [/OnlineStore]]] [2019-01-25T23:10:34.281+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447034281] [levelValue: 800] [[   OnlineStore was successfully deployed in 408
>   milliseconds.]] [2019-01-25T23:12:51.678+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=37 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1548447171678] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:12:51.688+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=37
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1548447171688] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:12:51.699+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=37
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1548447171699] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:12:51.863+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=37
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1548447171863] [levelValue: 800] [[   Loading application [OnlineStore] at
>   [/OnlineStore]]] [2019-01-25T23:12:51.879+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=37
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1548447171879] [levelValue: 800] [[   OnlineStore was successfully deployed in 213
>   milliseconds.]] [2019-01-25T23:15:05.639+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1548447305639] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:05.988+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=36
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1548447305988] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:05.993+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=36
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1548447305993] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:06.194+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=36
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1548447306194] [levelValue: 800] [[   Loading application [OnlineStore] at
>   [/OnlineStore]]] [2019-01-25T23:15:06.218+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=36
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1548447306218] [levelValue: 800] [[   OnlineStore was successfully deployed in 656
>   milliseconds.]] [2019-01-25T23:15:33.597+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=34 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447333597] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:33.623+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447333623] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:33.627+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] []
>   [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447333627] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:33.723+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447333723] [levelValue: 800] [[   Loading application [OnlineStore] at
>   [/OnlineStore]]] [2019-01-25T23:15:33.737+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=34
>   _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1548447333737] [levelValue: 800] [[   OnlineStore was successfully deployed in 190
>   milliseconds.]] [2019-01-25T23:15:36.371+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=228
>   _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1548447336371] [levelValue: 800] [[   Server shutdown initiated]] [2019-01-25T23:15:36.373+0300]
>   [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00028]
>   [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=228
>   _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1548447336373] [levelValue: 800] [[   Unregistered
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@7cfb4736
>   from service registry.]] [2019-01-25T23:15:36.373+0300] [glassfish
>   4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=228 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1548447336373] [levelValue: 800] [[   FileMonitoring
>   shutdown]] [2019-01-25T23:15:36.376+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO]
>   [NCLS-JMX-00002] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=228
>   _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1548447336376] [levelValue: 800] [[   JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:36.378+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00001]
>   [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=228
>   _ThreadName=Thread-29] [timeMillis: 1548447336378] [levelValue: 800] [[   JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.]]
>   [2019-01-25T23:15:36.541+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid:
>   _ThreadID=228 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1548447336541] [levelValue: 800] [[   JdbcRuntimeExtension, 
>   getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools =
>   [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource,
>   GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource,
>   GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool,
>   GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool,
>   GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool,
>   GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource]]]

Comment: пытаюсь запустить гласфиш из консоли командой asadmin start -domain domain1 и получаю ошибку Could not find or load main class files

Comment: Из Вашего предыдущего вопроса, речь идёт о курсах 2016 года. Попробуйте взять версию 8.2. Хотя, судя по логам, более вероятная причина проблемы - ошибка в проекте или его зависимостях. Но, это лишь моё предположение.

Comment: в проекте две jsp страницы ,даже если я их сейчас удаляю сервер заново не запускается.версии я пробовал все от 7й до 9й ,везде одно и тоже

Comment: удалил приложение ,перезапустил винду,нетбинс ,Гласфиш.захожу в нетбинс жму на гласфиш -запустить и получаю вот это     Sat Jan 26 00:14:23 GMT+03:00 2019 : Сетевой сервер Apache Derby Network Server - 10.9.1.0 - (1344872) запущен и готов принимать соединения на порту 1527 на {3} 
что это за хрень то?из консоли сервер тоже не подымается -пишет не мождет найти или загрузить мейн класс файлы какие то.создал через консоль новый домейн попробовал стартануть его -таже ошибка не может найти или загрузить мейн класс....

Comment: снес к чертям этот гласфиш - загружаю заново через нет бинс-он не загружается)) пишет папка не корректная указана,хорошо пытаюсь установить в папку в которую хочет он - пишет она отсуствует.я ее создаю вручную - пишет ее нет-захожу в директорию- он ее сам удалил)))) я так понимаю поэтому с этим глас фиш никто и не работает потом что это какое то насилие над организмом?

Comment: вообщем пока работает ,что помогло не знаю,отрубил все БД ,пока не нужные,проект переместил в папку путь к которой не содержит русских букв,убрал в админ консоли опцию maxpermsize ,еще как то плясал с бубном) но как мне кажется ошибка была в этой java DB,которая зачем то по дефолту подключаетя и кидает свои ошибки и гласфиш  сразу же отваливается